# Convergence of an independent but not identically distributed sequence of discrete random variables

Tags: probability-theory

> Suppose $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of independent random variables  such that
>   $$
> P\left(X_k=1-\frac1k\right)=1-\frac1k\qquad P\left(X_k=2-\frac1k\right)=\frac1k.
> $$
>   Define for each positive integer $n$, $Y_n=\prod_{k=1}^n X_k$. Using the martingale convergence theorem, one can show that $Y_n\to Y$ a.s. for some $Y$. What is the distribution of $Y$?

---

Several approaches have been tried, but I don't know how to go on due to the difficulties in computation:

- Let $Z_n=\log Y_n$ and calculate for every $t$ the limit of
  $$
  \prod_{k=1}^n\Bigg[\left(1-\frac1k\right)e^{it\log(1-1/k)}+\frac1ke^{it\log(2-1/k)}\Bigg].
  $$
- Check the Lindeberg or Lyapunov condition in order to use the CLT:
  $$
  E(Y_n)=1,\qquad EY^2_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1k-\frac{1}{k^2}\right),\quad\cdots
  $$

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I have an answer for the question. Note that $Y\geq 0$. One can show that $Y=0$ almost surely. 
Note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n>1.5)=\infty.
$$
Since $\{X_n\}$ are independent, the [second Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) implies that
$$
P(X_n>1.5\ \textrm{infinitely often})=1
$$
and thus $P(Y_{n+1}/Y_n>1.5\ \textrm{infinitely often})=1$, which implies that $Y_n\to Y$ almost surely cannot be true unless $P(Y=0)=1$.

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1}/Y_n>1.5$ infinitely often$)$ implies $\mathbb{P}(Y=0)=1$....? The event $\{X_n<1\}$ happens also infinitely often and it depends very much on how often the event $\{X_n>1.5\}$ happens compared to $\{X_n<1\}$.Actually, I believe that $\mathbb{P}(Y>0)>0$ due to Kakutani's theorem on product martingales.

Comment: @saz: If $Y_{n+1}(\omega)>1.5Y_{n}(\omega)$, then $Y_n(\omega)$ cannot converge to a positive real number.